# C# communication with nodejs

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js

I would like to create a GUI application in C# to act as a container for node js.
For example read files from a directory with node's file system api and then my C# program will create a list (like a ListView) to display those files.

Is this possible? Can anyone point me to a direction.
(I don't know how to search this on the internet)

Comment: Look into [Edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using [`edge.js`](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) for this. It will allow you to run C# code from within a Node.js app or [run Node.js code from within a C# app](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/48).

I've never personally used `edge.js` but the docs are pretty good and should get you up and running in no time.